# flutter get data from api and assign to array

Tags: arrays, json, http, flutter

List data;

i want to show response but when i try to assign jasonResponse to data
i get this error

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map'

so what should i do

how to assign array of object to data

```
Future<String> getJsonData() async{

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    Map data = {'sale_id': sharedPreferences.getInt("token")};

    var jsonResponse;
    var response = await http.post(
      "http://",
      body: json.encode(data),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"

      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      print('jsonRespnse');
      print(jsonResponse['developer_list']);
      if (jsonResponse != null) {
         setState(() {

          data = jsonResponse['developer_list'];

         });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` is a type `Map` but you are assigning a type `List`.

Simply, add a key with your value, like below:

```
data['developer_list'] = jsonResponse['developer_list'];
```

Make sure to access that list by `data['developer_list']`